# Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 - File Attachment Failed

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution App). I took photo using TAKEPHOTO options but couldn't save it back to Maximo, its giving below exception.

Logs:

```
2016-01-22 10:50:02.153 WorkExecution[1689:755353] got managebusy call busystate=true, busy window visible=true
2016-01-22 10:50:02.640 WorkExecution[1689:756415] [DEBUG] [NONE] Piggybacking event transmission
2016-01-22 10:50:02.643 WorkExecution[1689:756198] [DEBUG] [NONE] Flush called
2016-01-22 10:50:02.922 WorkExecution[1689:756415] File Transfer Finished with response code 404
2016-01-22 10:50:02.923 WorkExecution[1689:756415] FileTransferError {
    body = "Error 404: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /anywhereAttachment\n";
    code = 3;
    "http_status" = 404;
    source = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E7497A1-72B5-410C-A1E3-A35995D725AB/Documents/anywhere/maxadmin/WorkExecution/workOrder_1013/cdv_photo_001.png";
    target = "http://IP:PORT/MaximoAnywhere/anywhereAttachment";
}
2016-01-22 10:50:02.937 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: [StoreLock] lock: adding  to lock resource workOrder
    2016-01-22 10:50:03.422 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] PersistenceManager _findRecordsOnStore: (ignore if querybase exists)workOrderSpecResource queryBase: null query: {"_errored":1}: 155ms
2016-01-22 10:50:03.422 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] PersistenceManager - _filterExactMatchesIfNeeded: 0ms
2016-01-22 10:50:03.422 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [DATA] Data fetched. Returning to consumer
2016-01-22 10:50:03.485 WorkExecution[1689:755353] got managebusy call busystate=false, busy window visible=true
2016-01-22 10:50:03.485 WorkExecution[1689:755353] taking down busy window
2016-01-22 10:50:03.485 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden by application = true
2016-01-22 10:50:03.485 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden
2016-01-22 10:50:03.485 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] -[NotificationEx loadingStop:] in NotificationEx.m:150 :: Loading stop
2016-01-22 10:50:03.953 WorkExecution[1689:755353] ERROR: {"type":"business","error":{"invocationResult":{"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{},"oslc:message":"Upload failed - HTTP: 404. Contact your administrator.","oslc:statusCode":1,"spi:reasonCode":1}]},"invocationContext":null,"status":1,"errorCode":1,"errorMsg":"Upload failed - HTTP: 404. Contact your administrator.","isSuccessful":false},"additionalInfo":{"metadata":{"formulaFields":[{"index":true,"dataType":"string","name":"exactremoteid","local":true,"isComplex":false,"isRemote":false,"persistent":true},{"id":"aw473f3b38","index":true,"dataType":"string","persistent":true,"name":"starttimeISO","artifactId":"workOrder_starttimeISO_string","remoteName":"spi_wm:schedstart","local":true,"isComplex":false,"isRemote":false}],"queryBases":{"searchAllWorkOrders":"/oslc/os/oslcwodetail?savedQuery=getWithComplexQuery","getMyAssignedWork":"/oslc/os/oslcwodetail?savedQuery=getMyAssignedWork","WORKIOWN":"/oslc/os/oslcwodetail?savedQuery=WORKIOWN"},"queryBasesLabel":[{"name":"getMyAssignedWork","label":"getMyAssignedWork"},{"name":"WORKIOWN","label":"WORKIOWN"}],"adapter":"OSLCGenericAdapter","name":"workOrder","_classInstance":{},"_urlBase":"http://IP:PORT/maximo","inMemory":false,"isSystem":false,"pageSize":40,"refreshOnLogin":false,"serverOnlyMode":false,"orderBy":"wonum asc","additionalData":false,"isAttachment":false,"maxFetchDataLimit":500,"fields":[{"name":"__tempId","dataType":"integer","precision":0,"index":true,"local":true,"isComplex":false,"isRemote":false,"persistent":true},{"name":"remoteid","dataType":"string","precision":0,"remoteName":"rdf:about","local":false,"index":true,"isComplex":false,"isRemote":true,"persistent":true},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is look like you are missing attachmentServlet

Try this troubleshooting 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.2/tshoot/ts_attachments_servlet.html?lang=en

if this attachment is missing then you required to follow ,  MaximoAnywhere.war deployment process , you can find same on anywhere knowledge center.

also make sure your attachment configuration correct in maximo , you can follow this 
doclink configration in maximo 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21312993